# How to parse a single json object responses?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am trying to parse/convert a get response to a POJO. I have the User class below and the Controller class.

In the getUsers() method, I am able to parse the request by using  `ParameterizedTypeReference` with wrapper class. However, I am not able to parse the "single object" response.

For getUser response, if I use the same code by changing the `ParameterizedTypeReference<UsersWrapper>()` as `ParameterizedTypeReference<User>()` or use the code shown in the getUser method, I get `null` values for my User class.

I assume I am not able to parse the JSON because of the `{ "user": {..` wrapper.

How can I have the values for the User class from JSON by using:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public User getUser(@PathVariable long id) {}
```

JSON:

```
    {
    "user": {
        "id": 375607441100,
        "url": "https://example.com/users/375607441100.json",
        "name": "example-user",
        "email": "example-user@hotmail.com",
        "created_at": "2020-11-25T09:13:40Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-11-25T09:16:44Z",
        "time_zone": "Europe/Warsaw",
        "iana_time_zone": "Europe/Warsaw",
        "phone": null,
        "shared_phone_number": null,
        "photo": null,
        "locale_id": 1,
        "locale": "en-US",
        "organization_id": null,
        "role": "admin",
        "verified": true,
        "external_id": null,
        "tags": [],
        "alias": null,
        "active": true,
        "shared": false,
        "shared_agent": false,
        "last_login_at": "2020-11-25T09:16:35Z",
        "two_factor_auth_enabled": null,
        "signature": null,
        "details": null,
        "notes": null,
        "role_type": null,
        "custom_role_id": null,
        "moderator": true,
        "ticket_restriction": null,
        "only_private_comments": false,
        "restricted_agent": false,
        "suspended": false,
        "chat_only": false,
        "default_group_id": 360005501980,
        "report_csv": false,
        "user_fields": {}
    }
}
```

User class:

```
@Data
public class User {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String role;
}
```

UsersWrapper:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UsersWrapper {
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public UsersWrapper() {
    }
}
```

Controller getUsers():

```
@GetMapping
    public List<User> getUsers() {

        UsersWrapper claims = new UsersWrapper();

        try {
            ResponseEntity<UsersWrapper> claimResponse = restTemplate.exchange(
                    resourceUrl,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    request(), // headers with basicAuth -> username:token
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<UsersWrapper>() {
                    });

            if (claimResponse != null && claimResponse.hasBody()) {
                claims = claimResponse.getBody();
            }
        } catch (
                RestClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<User> users = claims.getUsers();

        return users;
}
```

getUser():

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable long id) {

        String url = resourceUrl + "/" + id;
        ResponseEntity<User> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                request(), User.class);

        User user = response.getBody();
        return user;
}
```

Comment: You are not asking a question. I can make a guess: you get two different responses for users, and you are asking how to use the same UserWrapper class (which expects an array of users to be in the payload) to parse a response which has only a single user property in it, no array. Is that what you want to ask?

Comment: Or, to complete Gimby's assumption, you can modify the response like this: https://restfulapi.net/json-array/ i.e.  
[{
    "id": 375607441100,
    "name": "example-user1"
  },
  {
    "id": 375607441100,
    "name": "example-user2"
  }
]

Comment: Also if you want to recieve an array of `User`s, you do not need to use a wrapper class but you can directly use `new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<User>>`

Comment: @Gimby I am not sure how to parse the "user" object when I request it by id. For example, I am using the same code in the getUsers request (instead of UsersWrapper -> User), I receive `null` values. `ParameterizedTypeReference<User>()`
`{
    "id": 0,
    "name": null,
    "email": null,
    "role": null,
    "numOfTickets": 0
}`

Answer (score 0):

Creating the following wrapper class with `@JsonProperty("user")` solved the case.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserWrapper {
    private UserDTO user;

    public UserWrapper() {
    }

    @JsonProperty("user")
    public UserDTO getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```